# Need help deserializing json data into a list of objects for a console application

Tags: c#, json, serialization

```
{"232341":{"id":232341,"name":"HCaKpdWjUG5Coh32","profileIconId":-1,"summonerLevel":1,"revisionDate":1320361798000},
"232340":{"id":232340,"name":"f6Q3RQEgQSwO3SRT","profileIconId":-1,"summonerLevel":1,"revisionDate":1323137663000},
"232362":{"id":232362,"name":"To1UB04fHW74LFRT","profileIconId":-1,"summonerLevel":1,"revisionDate":1323137663000}
```

So this is my json output that i receive and i want to write out only the data in a format of my choosing. But i am getting into trouble when i try to deserialize it. I currently have 2 classes.

```
    public class DataContainer
{
    public List<Summoner> summoners { get; set; }
}


public class Summoner
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}
```

And i deserialize it with the help of this line of code :

```
var observation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LDataContainer>(json);
```

But now when i debug it the variable observation is null. It doesnt add any summoners. I have tried everything i can but this deserializing in C# is really confusing me right now.

Comment: That json isn't valid

Comment: How so ? Because i also thought i needed to add something like summdata around it but i am kinda stuck on that too. But i am receiving this data through an api so what would you say i should do here ?

Comment: If you mean the missing } at the end. That just because i did a bad job cutting my json short.

Comment: `Dictionary<string, Summoner> deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Summoner>>(json);`

Comment: You are my hero Plutonix. Not only did you fix my code. But i just understood this deserializing a lot better. Thanks a bunch !